# Complex Join using criteria builder

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following code, where Class has a relationship with Student through students property.

```
Root<SchoolClass> root = criteria.from(SchoolClass.class);
Join<SchoolClass, Student> classStudentMapping = root.join("students");
```

This is working fine, no problem. But now I want to join to another entity which has no relationship with Classes but only with student. say Address... How I can join using criteria builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, start the secon join from `classStudentMapping`:

```
Join<Student, Address> = classStudentMapping.join("address");
```

This is possible because the interface involved in this process, [`From<Z,X>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html), extends `Path<X>`, therefore `classStudentMapping` is a `Path<Student>`.